# How to create descriptive statistics table of a given style?

Tags: tables, stata

I want to create a descriptive statistics table which looks like this: [image]

especially how the two categories: insured  and non insured appear side by side.

I tried estpost tabstat by categories in stata and used esttab to save the table in latex, but the resultant table has the categories vertically and doesn't look anything like the one in the picture.

Can anyone suggest how the table like the one in screenshot can be replicated?

Also, is it possible to obtain it through some stata commands, or must be done by hand in latex?

Thanks

Comment: Hello there! This is Tom from the Overleaf Support Team. Please note that I removed the [tag:overleaf] tag as this is not directly Overleaf-related. I hope you manage to solve the issue!

Comment: Please provide what you try so far. Retyping your table (knowing, that you already have some code for it) is not a fun. Help us to help your.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something to start

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\noindent{\centering\scriptsize
\begin{tabular}{lSSSSSS}
\toprule
& \multicolumn{3}{l}{Insured} & \multicolumn{3}{l}{Uninsured}\\
\cmidrule(lr){2-4}\cmidrule(l){5-7}
Variable & {Weighted mean} & {Minimum} & {Maximum} & {Weighted mean} & {Minimum} & {Maximum} \\
\midrule
Social cohesion at commune level (1 low to 5 high) & 4.121 & 3.646 & 4.750 & 4.103 & 3.646 & 4.453 \\
\bottomrule 
\end{tabular}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In  `S`column types, `\multicolumn{1}{c}`  is not necessary to centre a column header: a simple pair of braces will do it.

Comment: @Bernard Thank you, I didn't know it. I've corrected it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with `stata` commands nor syntax (since I newer use it), however, if it generate some table, you can manually reformat.

[image]

Above table is produced by use of `tabularray` package and two libraries which load `booktabs` and `siunitx` packages:

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}

\begin{document}

    \begin{table}
    \centering
\sisetup{table-format=2.3}
\caption{???}
\label{tab:statistic?}
    \begin{tblr}{colspec= {Q[l,m,wd=0.4\linewidth] *{3}{Q[m,c,si]}},
                 row{1} = {font=\bfseries},
                 row{3-Y} = {belowsep=3pt}
                } 
    \toprule
\SetCell[r=2]{c}    
    &   \SetCell[c=3]{c} {{{Insured}}}
        & & &   \SetCell[c=3]{c} {{{Uninsured}}}   
                &   &                                       \\
    \cmidrule[lr]{2-4}\cmidrule[l]{5-7}
Variable 
    & {{{Weighted mean}}}   & {{{Minimum}}} & {{{Maximum}}} 
    & {{{Weighted mean}}}   & {{{Minimum}}} & {{{Maximum}}} \\
    \midrule
Social cohesion at commune level (1 low to 5 high) 
    & 4.121 & 3.646 & 4.750 & 4.103 & 3.646 & 4.453         \\
Index of networks ...
    &16.058 & 5.521 &49,147 &12.478 & 2.796 &49.147         \\
%
Income (annual consumption expenditure '000s VND
    &   \num{13 709}    &   \num{840}   &   \num{103 944} 
    &   \num{13 532}    &   \num{432}   &   \num{168 000}   \\   
%
    \bottomrule
    \end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Table is not complete, but missed rows should be simple to add.